# Выводит Nan после вычисления

Tags: c++, массивы, nan

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int row = 10;
    const int col = 10;
    int n, m,k=0,L = 0;
    double a= L/k;
    int arr[row][col];
    cout << "Enter n:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter m:";
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter arr[" << i << "][" << j << "]:";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
            k++;
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][0] < 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] * (-1);
                    L++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    cout << "New array is:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "The specific gravity of the elements that changed the value" << a<<
        endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Задание:нужно заменить знак элементов матрицы на противоположный в рядах, которые начинаются с отрицательного элемента.Вычислить удельный вес элементов, которые поменяли знак

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду

Answer (score 1):

Скажите, чему у вас равно `a`:

```
int n, m, k=0, L = 0;
double a = L/k;
```

Просто посчитайте его на бумажке :)

Больше вопросов нет?

Comment: зачем в теле  if (arr[i][0] < 0) еще один цикл?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это вы у меня спрашиваете? :) я ответил только на заданный вопрос...

Comment: нет, это дополнительная подсказка автору вопроса